# Does video.js video player supports youtube videos?

Tags: html, youtube, video.js, video-player

I need customized HTML5 video player, also I need youTube videos to play. I got one HTML 5 video player vidoeJS http://www.videojs.com/, but I am not able to play a youTube video in this player. How to make youTube player to play using this player.

Answer (score 16):

There's a video.js plugin for YouTube support.
https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube

And Vimeo.
https://github.com/eXon/videojs-vimeo

Comment: It looks like the code of `eXon` was moved in-house as it redirects to: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could use [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) which supports both HTML5 video and YouTube.